# Which plugin / module of Spring Sec OAuth should be used in Grails 3.x?

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to migrate my Grails 2.5 project into Grails 3.1.4. In my old BuildConfig I was using the following:

```
plugins {
  compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC5'
  compile ':spring-security-oauth:2.1.0-RC4'
  compile ':spring-security-oauth-facebook:0.2'
  compile ':spring-security-oauth-google:0.3.1'
}
```

Now my build.gradle looks like:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
  //compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth:2.1.0-RC4'
  //compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth-facebook:0.2'
  //compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth-google:0.3.1'
}
```

The build is successfull, until I uncomment the commented lines. That leads to errors like:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
 Could not find spring-security-core.zip (org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1).
   Searched in the following locations:
     https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/3.1.1/spring-security-core-3.1.1.zip
```

So, what is the proper way to install & use OAuth (2?) plugin in Grails 3?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I forget to reply but @injecteer I am currently testing following plugins with Grails 3.2.2 and its working so far. So I think accepted answer is no longer valid.

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2:1.1.0"
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2-facebook:1.0.0"
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2-google:1.1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

No Spring Security OAuth-plugins are available for Grails 3.x for now. The only option is to use client-side JS-based solutions. The same way the `Android` / `iOS` authentications are working, w/o any server-side plugins.

Comment: Sorry but plugin working only package name is different. Please find my answer below.

Comment: do you want Authentication and authorization plugin  @injecteer ?? in the grails