# Customise Spring Security 3.1.1 Login form in Grails 3

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-3.1

I have declared Spring Security in my application.yml as a dependency and when running my app the default login form works as expected. I would like to style the form so my application is seamless.

In views/auth I have auth.gsp which contains the following code:

```
<form method="POST" action="${resource(file: 'j_spring_security_check')}">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td><td><g:textField name="j_username"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td><td><input name="j_password" type="password"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><g:submitButton name="login" value="Login"/></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

This form appears as expected however when submitting the form nothing happens. I'm assuming it's because `{resource(file: 'j_spring_security_check')}` is not the action that it should be going to. I have got this code from [here](http://spring.io/blog/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/) and I believe this is written with Grails 2 in mind. Any idea what the correct action is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is the working customised login form:

```
<form method="POST" action="${resource(file: '/login/authenticate')}" class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading text-center">Login</h2>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>

    <label class="checkbox text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="rememberMe" name="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
```

Key things to note are:

- `j_spring_security_check` is now `/login/authenticate`
- `j_username` is now `username`
- `j_password` is now `password`

Documentation for Spring security 3 which is used for Grails 3 is [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#introduction)

Answer (score 1):

I'm shocked to find that a blog post from six years ago isn't 100% correct. Perhaps you'll have better luck reading [the documentation](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html), in particular the "What’s New in Version 3.0" section.

Comment: a bit offtopic, but can you please comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175154/which-plugin-module-of-spring-sec-oauth-should-be-used-in-grails-3-x ?