# dynamic database in grails

Tags: spring, grails

I am trying to create a project with grails 3.1.1. I want every user to their own a database. Is it possible to create a project like that in grails? For example I have a domain

```
class User {
  String name
  String username
  String password
  String databaseName

  static constraints = {
      name(blank: false)
  }
}
```

So, every user can access their database with field `databaseName`. Can anyone can tell me what should I do?

Comment: This is odd. If you insist on 1 db per user, why not run instances of the same app on different ports each with it's own datasource configuration and a separate login module which redirects a user to their appropriate instance? Don't know about dynamic configuring a datasource at runtime, but if you add a new user you would need to create a new db anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not possible with Grails' convention over configuration paradigm, since it is heavily tailored towards mapping of entities to a datasource (not necessarily a database).

I really wonder about a use case, where you would want one database schema per user. To implement this use case, you'll need 100% custom code (and I'd even avoid using an ORM, since configuration of an `EntityManager` seems nigh impossible in this context, so better use vanilla JDBC instead).

Comment: in my case, every user will have a big database size, for example, if i have 10 users and i am using single database, i think mysql not fit with this size, for example every user need minimun database until 1GB, then 10 users must be 10GB,

Comment: 10GB for one database is not very big for a MySQL database. You can easily scale towards Terrabyte dimensions without any performance problems (depends heavily on your schema of course). But @injecteer is right, [Multi-Tenant Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/multi-tenant-core) seems to fit for your use case.

Comment: really? 10GB is not a very big data, then can you tell me maximum size? because now i confuse to choose a database, every user need minimum size for a database was 3GB, and minimun user maybe until 100 users

Comment: The answer is "it depdens". It is very difficult to give you more detailed advice without understanding the context and use cases of your application. I really don't understand which kind of Grails application (which is tailored towards a quite traditional web application architecture) does need your suggested design, but that is totally up to you and your context. You can scale relational databases to many terrabytes of data, but there might be other persistence better suited for this task.

Comment: @akiong looking at the table size limit on [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/table-size-limit.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/table-size-limit.html) The limit for 1 table (at least 2gb depending on OS) already exceeds your expected size for 1 user for the **whole** db for 1 user.

Comment: @Guus All major OS which should be considered as a production environment for a MySQL database allow multiple TB. Or have a look at the (better) relational database alternative [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/about/) which allows for up to 32TB size per table.

Comment: i see this article http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/table-size-limit.html, it saids 4TB on linux for every table, i think this size already enough ..
at least i know about maximum size of database depend on  my table.

Comment: Also check out this paragraph:
_The effective maximum table size for MySQL databases is usually determined by operating system constraints on file sizes, not by MySQL internal limits. The following table lists some examples of operating system file-size limits. This is only a rough guide and is not intended to be definitive._

Answer (score 1):

That sounds wrong though. You can probably have one user containing an entity rather than a database.

Comment: not a user database, i mean user in a project, for example, username "abc" using database "abc", and username "xyz" using database with database name "xyz"

Answer (score -1):

[Grails Multi-Tenant Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/multi-tenant-core) is what you need

Comment: Except for the small complication that it doesn't work with Grails 2 or Grails 3

Comment: @BurtBeckwith never used that one personally

Comment: @BurtBeckwith can you shed some light on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175154/which-plugin-module-of-spring-sec-oauth-should-be-used-in-grails-3-x ?

Comment: You haven't used the plugin but you're recommending others use it? That's pretty much the exact opposite of how things are supposed to work on SO :)

Comment: @BurtBeckwith well, I can help others with my plugin-awareness :) many people out there have never even heard of multi-tenant. Now serious, I actually evaluated the plugin several years ago to include it into one of my projects. On the other hand, you don't think that other "answers" provide any relevant info on the topic, do you?